# Passing ng-repeat local object to directive controller is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass my `ng-repeat` local object to directive. I need to access the data from that object inside my directive controller. I'm confused about `iso-lated scope` and controller scope. Why it's not working.

> [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/tbhhsf87/1/) Fiddle about what I'm trying

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="MainController">

    <div ng-repeat="document in documents">
        <name-row 
            document-element="document">
        </name-row>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
module.directive('nameRow', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            documentElement : '=document',

        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.documentElement);
        },
        template:
'        <ul>' +      
'            <li>' +
'                <a>' +
'                    {{documentElement.targetPrice}}' +
'                </a>' +
'            </li>' +
'        </ul>'
    };
});
```

I just want to understand why it's not working. I don't want to do with any alternatives like accessing this in link function etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used alias for attribute `=document`, You attribute should be `document` instead of `document-element`.

```
<div ng-repeat="document in documents">
    <name-row 
        document="document">
    </name-row>
</div>
```

---

Other way would be you could remove an alias of attribute in isolated property declaration.

```
scope: {
   documentElement : '=', //just have `=` instead of `=document`
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in directive. Variable name was wrong

```
module.directive('nameRow', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            documentElement : '=documentElement',

        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.documentElement);
        },
        template:
'        <ul>' +      
'            <li>' +
'                <a>' +
'                    {{documentElement.targetPrice}}' +
'                </a>' +
'            </li>' +
'        </ul>'
    };
});
```

Comment: no need to explicitly have `=documentElement` only `=` is fine